# Startup applications in an assigned workspace

Tags: startup, workspaces

I can get applications to start on login using the GUI applet in Ubuntu.

Is there anything that can be added to the command line so it starts in an assigned workspace?

I haven't been able to get `gdevilspie` to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using compizconfig-setting-manager. In the Place Windows Plugin you can add apps you would like to start on a certain workspace and then select the workspace using XY coordinates.